# Why cl.exe change the extern function name used in my code?

Tags: ida, winapi, nasm

So basically I my nasm syntax asm code, I use some extern functions like this:

```
extern _printf
extern __imp__Sleep@4
....
call _printf
call    [__imp__Sleep@4]
```

Then I use nasm to assemble it into obj:

```
nasm -f win32 test.asm
```

Then I use IDA Pro to disassemble test.obj, I can see code like this:

[image]

See, extern function name like **_printf** has been kept.

But when I link this obj file:

```
cl /MT z:\\windows\\test.obj /link kernel32.lib libcmt.lib /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
```

Then I use IDA Pro to disassemble test.exe, I can see code like this:

[image]

See, the function name of **_printf** has been changed.

I know basically after static link, the code of _printf has been put into the test.exe, in the subroutine of **sub_409C9B**

But basically **I have to make the name of extern declared functions unchangeable**, because I need to reverse engineering the test.exe and do some modify/remove towards those functions, and once PE exe lost the name info, I can not locate those targeting functions.

So my question is:

Why cl.exe will change the name of those functions, and is there any way to stop the change(I mean keep the function name unchangeable during the link time)?

Comment: That is why there exists signatures for IDA (Flirt) to detect such standard library functions. Apply them and see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got some kind of [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

The truth is: it's IDA who so to say "changes" the name of (something she thinks is) a function from absolutely nothing to `sub_{address}`. Why on earth would `PE-file` have non-exported symbols stored in it? Some kind of masochism? To give a candy to reversers?

Thus, you have at least three ways of dealing with your problem:

- pray and hope that IDA's [FLIRT](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/tech/flirt/in_depth.shtml) will heuristically recognize `printf`;
- `link` your program with debug-info: [`-debug`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235413.aspx) which tells linker to generate [`pdb`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database)-file which IDA will query for all the symbols stored for your application;
- tell linker to [`-export:printf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235424.aspx) so that it's name will be in export directory and you can get it's address easily even programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

When `printf()` is called as an external function, the Windows loader needs to look up the address of the `printf()` function by-name at run-time so that the caller can find the `printf()` code.

When `printf()` is called as an embedded library function, the compiler already knows the address of the `printf()` function at compile-time, and thus doesn't need to embed the function's name in the executable.

If you want the `printf()` name to automatically show in your disassembly, either export debug symbols or stick with using external DLLs. Alternatively, you may be able to use IDA's FLIRT libraries to identify the `printf()` function in the embedded library code.